# Mongoose if (!this.modelSchemas[name]) error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema, mongoose-web-server

Whenever I try connecting using the code below,

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 
// var Model = mongoose.model.bind(mongoose); didnt work

var imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 
  name: String,
  dob: String,
  breed: String,
  details: String,
    img:
    {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }
 
});

module.exports = new mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema);
```

I get this error logged in the console

```
if (!this.modelSchemas[name]) {
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Image' of undefined
```

I had tried the model bind mongoose as suggested on another page,  but that doesn't work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model` is a method that returns the model. You shouldn't call it with `new`:

```js
module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema);
```